# Использует ли Microsoft в новых версиях Windows .Net Framework?

Tags: .net, windows

Microsoft активно пропагандирует .NET Framework, но используют ли они его сами для написания какого-либо функционала(Новых модулей) в свежих версиях Windows?

Ведь сам Windows написан на C++ и соотвественно, они либо продолжают писать на С++ его, либо свежие модули все таки пишут на .Net Framework.

Comment: Что есть "свежий" и что в вашем понимании "модуль"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов., свежий-написанные с 0 на .Net, модуль какая-то часть системы, например сервис, системная утилита и все такое.

Comment: Если утилита... Powerschell? `Windows PowerShell 4.0 requires the full installation of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5`

Comment: .NET Framework начиная с Windows Vista является неотъемлемой частью операционной системы (присутствует по умолчанию). Эту платформу уже используют многие приложения, т.о. изъята она точно не будет, тем более, что Майкрософт активно её развивает. Данную тему считаю неконструктивной.

Comment: @iluxa1810 большая часть системных приложений в Win 8 / Win 10 - это Universal Apps. Которые написаны на .NET. Из сервисов - в тот же IIS .NET прописался достаточно глубоко.

Answer (score -1):

Все главные части операционной системы Windows написаны на **C**.

Windows не требует для запуска **VCRedistributable** и **.NET Framework**. Следовательно они в том виде, в котором предлагаются нам - программистам, не используются для создания ос Windows. Предустановленный NET можно удалить и система будет работать.

NET предоставляется как средство создания небольших по размеру C# программ и он встроен в Windows уже "из коробки". В систему не предустановлен VCRedist (Visual C++).